# SQL Error: The Insert statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just learning the SQL language. Trying to insert data into a table but keep getting the following error:

> "The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint
>   "JOB_JOBCODE". The conflict occurred in database "qwerty", table
>   "dbo.Job", column 'jobCode'."

Code:

This is the table I'm creating, nothing fancy

```
CREATE TABLE Job(
jobCode char(4),
jobdesc varchar(50),
--ADD CONSTRAINT PK JPB CODE
CONSTRAINT PK_JobCode PRIMARY KEY(jobCode) ,
CONSTRAINT JOB_JOBCODE CHECK (jobCode in ('CAST’, ‘ENGI’, ‘INSP’, ‘PMGR')) );
```

This is the data that I'm inserting

```
INSERT INTO Job VALUES ('CAST', 'Cast Member);
```

Any help would be appreciated, Im not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: if your script is _exactly_ that, use a proper apostrophe instead of `’`. i.e. `jobCode in ('CAST', 'ENGI', 'INSP', 'PMGR')`

Comment: As ZLK points out, your single quotes aren't true `'`. Given the fact that you have one at the beginning and end, if your job code isn't exactly `CAST’, ‘ENGI’, ‘INSP’, ‘PMGR`, it will fail.

Comment: You're also missing a quote on your `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Once the obvious errors are fixed, the code runs fine:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6d51e.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query for inserting values into **Job** table

```
INSERT INTO Job VALUES ('CAST', 'Cast Member');
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this to fix your check literal error:

```
ALTER TABLE Job DROP JOB_JOBCODE

ALTER TABLE Job ADD CONSTRAINT JOB_JOBCODE CHECK (jobCode IN ('CAST', 'ENGI', 'INSP', 'PMGR'))
```

Then use the explicit column form of the insert:

```
INSERT INTO Job (jobCode, jobdesc)
VALUES ('CAST', 'Cast Member')
```

Make sure to use the proper literal delimiter `'`.